# Could someone help me understand about the difference between standard linux base and linux filesystem hierarchy

Tags: linux

I am studying for Linux certification and I would like a more detailed text about standard linux base and linux filesystem hierarchy.

Could   help me on the meaning of this topic:

"standard linux base and linux filesystem hierarchy"

thank you very much for  attention

Comment: I think you would find your answers in search engines much faster

Answer (score 1):

https://refspecs.linuxbase.org/FHS_3.0/fhs/index.html

This document explains the Linux base FHS.

/bin : Essential user command binaries (for use by all users)

/boot : Static files of the boot loader

/dev : Device files

/etc : Host-specific system configuration

/home : User home directories (optional)

/lib : Essential shared libraries and kernel modules

/lib : Alternate format essential shared libraries (optional)

/media : Mount point for removable media

/mnt : Mount point for a temporarily mounted filesystem

/opt : Add-on application software packages

/root : Home directory for the root user (optional)

/run : Run-time variable data

/sbin : System binaries

/srv : Data for services provided by this system

/tmp : Temporary files

The /usr Hierarchy (Universal system resources, not required for system boot)

The /var Hierarchy (Variable files, such as logs)

Comment: explaining using your words would be helpful. Subject experience would be good!

Comment: Added some more explanation.

Comment: Is there anything in particular you're looking for? I'd be happy to add more info if you could me more specific.

Comment: and about "standard linux base"? ... all linux-based systems have FHS? if  don’t follow the patterns, what happens, there are other patterns

Comment: Linux based systems follow the FHS, yes. The link I sent you and the content I wrote was from linuxbase.org.